# Speed test results always the same?

Tags: networking, router, internet, speed, modem

So i'm trying to measure my internet speed to see if i get the speed where i'm paying for. I read that with a direct connection to your modem you get a closer measure of your promised internet speed. I'm testing my speed with different speed tests online, including http://www.speedtest.net and speed tests by my own ISP.

 However, it makes no difference if i have a direct connection(disabled any other connection aka router and wifi). Even with all my devices on and testing on a other computer i get the same results as a directed conncetion. And yes, i'm using a LAN cable connection.

 Is there anything that i'm not aware of?

 
 I appreciate any help as i'm no expert in this area.

 Kind regads, Nkmol

Comment: Perhaps the stats you get back are correct?

Comment: Unless the speed you're getting is (much) lower than you pay for (you are not telling us that), isn't that a good thing? I would be more worried if I get various results

Comment: Well i don't really know how this works, but i thought the total speed you get is splitting up to your devices? We have like 10 devices connected to the internet, shouldn't the total of that be the speed i should get from my modem?(every cable device has the same speed).

Comment: Speed test them all at exactly the same time and you might see a split, but don't expect each device to necessarily get 1/10th your speed.

Comment: I see, that's where i completely missed it. Thanks, really usefull information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Network connections will only run as fast as the slowest component. Wifi and LAN connections tend to be in the 100s of Mbps under good conditions, so it is unlikely that these would slow down your internet speed. The only case in which Wifi will be affected is in an area with a lot of other Wifi devices, such as a block of flats.

I would not be alarmed that your speed tests are all giving the same result. If the result is significantly lower than you expect, then it may be a problem with your router or ISP.

Comment: Yea, thanks for clarification. It seems it's my ISP. Thanks for you help!